# How to access EasyRTC in Ionic Framework

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework, android-emulator, easyrtc

I want to build video call mobile app using EasyRTC Framework and Ionic

In browser my ionic project work well when i combine with easyRTC

[image]

> i setting in my index.html ionic project to connect with easyRTC like
>   this

```
<script src="http://localhost:3000/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost:3000/node/easyrtc.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost:3000/js/videortc.js"></script>
```

> before i build to apk, i change index.html like this image below because emulator
>   can read localhost in 10.0.2.2

```
<script src="http://10.0.2.2:3000/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://10.0.2.2:3000/node/easyrtc.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://10.0.2.2:3000/js/videortc.js"></script>
```

and then i build ionic project

> $ ionic build android

but video cannot appear in emulator android

anyone can help me ?
or give me some advice for build video call mobile app using ionic framework

Answer (score 0):

This link might help you, it does not use EasyRTC instead it employs apiRTC.

After installing plugin, you need to check source code folder "ionic-3-video-calling-using-webrtc/src/pages/home/". You also need to add 'NativeAudio' to app.module.ts file. Remember that 'The template does not work on its own so that you have to create a new project'.

https://github.com/nakulkundaliya/ionic-3-video-calling-using-webrtc